# Neighbors of second order

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

#### Given a directed graph with a few million edges, I am trying to find, for each node:

1. A list of neighbors of neighbors (let's call them `two_nei`).
2. The number of common neighbors with each of the `two_nei` (called `cn`).

#### The way I am approaching this problem is:

1. Creating a `dict` with each node as the key and a `list` containing all the neighbors as the value (`neighbor_dictionary`).
2. Creating a `dict` with each node as the key and a `list` containing all the neighbors of neighbors (`two_nei` for this node) as the value (`second_dictionary`).
3. Now I want to create a `list` (for the lack of knowing what to do), with a `dict` for every node in the graph. Each of these dictionaries will contain each `two_nei` of the node as the key and the value will be the number of common neighbors they have.

As you can see, this gets easily complicated. I am sure there is a simpler and more elegant way to do this in python. I am a math guy and I haven't had classes in neither data structures nor algorithms, but I am sure we could use queues to work this out.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) is easy going and well-documented. [`scipy.sparse.csgraph`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html) is designed for large graphs (up to 2**31 vertices, I believe), terse, new and exciting. Networkx has a function for exporting to SciPy, search its documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function which returns the number of shared second neighbors of two nodes in a graph. It uses [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) for the graph. Depending how much data is in each node and how densely connected your graph is, this may not work since it creates potentially large sets in memory.

```
def num_shared_second_neighbors(graph, node1, node2):
    """Number of second neighbors shared by node1 and node2 in graph."""
    return len(set(second_neighbors(graph, node1)).intersection(set(second_neighbors(graph, node2))))

def second_neighbors(graph, node):
    """Yield second neighbors of node in graph.
    Neighbors are not not unique!
    """
    for neighbor_list in [graph.neighbors(n) for n in graph.neighbors(node)]:
        for n in neighbor_list:
            yield n
```

The function `second_neighbors` is a generator that yields non-unique second neighbors of a node by doing a simple graph traversal. The function `num_shared_second_neighbors` simply returns the number of nodes in the intersection of the sets of seconds neighbors of two nodes.

Comment: There is a mistake in `second_neighbors` function - the generator contain also the node we are giving. For this reason `num_shared_second_neighbors` return too many (+2) shared neighbours.

Comment: Unless it's the point of the second neighborhood. o.o Even if it is, it is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your desired functions written with [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html):

#### 1. A list of neighbors of neighbors

```py
def get_second_neighbors(graph, node) -> list:
    """
    Returns a list of unique second neighbors for a given node in the graph.
    """
    return [second_neighbor 
            for first_neighbor in graph.neighbors(node)
            for second_neighbor in graph.neighbors(first_neighbor) 
            if second_neighbor != node])
```

#### 2. The number of shared neighbors

```
def get_num_shared_neighbors(graph, node1, node2) -> int:
    """
    Returns a number of second neighbors shared by node1 and node2 in the graph.
    """
    return len(set.intersection(set(get_second_neighbors(graph, node1)), 
                                set(get_second_neighbors(graph, node2))))
```

I hope the *list comprehension* made it *elegant* and understandable.